# How can I validate the textbox is string using selenium webdriver c#

Tags: selenium, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver

In y project i need to validate the textbox is string, textbox is data etc. Can some one help me in getting the value typed on the text box

Answer (score 0):

You can get value from attribute 'value'.

```
string textInput = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("css-expression")).GetAttribute("value");
```